# How can I use Ribbon Chart In Powerbi to select Stacked Graph

Tags: azure, powerbi

How to use ribbon chart so that I select block in that ribbon chart can it be possible I know that we cannot select a block in stacked barchart in Powerbi but something like this can be possible with ribbon chart??

Comment: Has nobody have answer to this??

Comment: Your run on sentence is very difficult to understand. I think you'll have more luck if you explained more clearly.